# relate registered user to specific content in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I have a selectable field on user registration page with "Topic" name.
Also have a "Topic" selectable filed on my specific content type.

I want my users can see only our contents with our "Topic"

note that only administrator can create content. users only can see content and don't able to post content.

Answer (score 2):

Create your "Topic" names as roles and content types. Display the roles as the drop down in your user registration form. Then use Content_access module ( http://drupal.org/project/content_access ) to restrict access to the content types based on user roles.

Comment: tnx for ur good solution. how can i display the roles as the drop down?

Comment: In the hook_form_alter() function  use user_roles() function to get all the roles and display it as a drop down. Let me know if you need further information.